# css issue on cordova (different bottom border width of li)?

Tags: android, css, cordova, uiwebview

I try to make simple list with bottom line on each item. It looks like all good in chrome browser but I get diferent lines thickness on Android 4.0.4 (cordova uiwebview):

[image]

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}

li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Some text
    </li>
    <li>
        Some text again
    </li>
    <li>
        Another text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    </li>
    <li>
        Another text again
    </li>
    <li>
        Some another text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    </li>
    <li>
        Some another text again bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    </li>
    <li>
        Some text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    </li>
    <li>
        Some text bla bla bla bla bla 
    </li>
    <li>
        Some text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    </li>
    <li>
        Some text bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    </li>
    <li>
        Some text bla bla bla bla bla 
    </li>
    <li>
        Some text
    </li>
    <li>
        Some text
    </li>
</ul>
```

I had tried to [reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) user agent stylesheet settings but it not helps

Comment: That's... weird. I can't say I know why this is happening but if you can't figure it out you might want to try something like appending </hr> to each item instead of a border - perhaps that will work better. Here's a JSFiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/8Lpgk/2/

Comment: Thanks, there are simpler realization of your idea `li:afrer {
    content: "<hr/>"
}` but the issue is still not gone...

Comment: I found some solution applicable for my app: do not use a 1px elements at all. `2px solid silver` works like a charm (all lines have similar thickness). But I am still look for better solution becouse this is ...weird

Comment: That really is weird; it might just be a bug.  If I get a chance today I'll try it out on my own device to see if I can replicate the problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, do you have found a solution beardmeaning?

Comment: Martin van Haeften,I did not find any solution. But I found some "weird" approach: just change lines width from 1px to 2px. It is not a solution but it looks better. Sorry for late answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JavaScript to set the list item height to be an even number (as close as possible to the list item's real item height) will solve this problem perfectly when rendering! For example:

```
$.each(liArr, function(idx, li){
    $Li = $(li);
    height = parseInt($Li.height());
    if(height % 2 != 0) $Li.height(height +1);
});
```